# Facebook post embed not scrollable

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

This is the embed code I got from Facebook

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbrendan.domotor%2Fposts%2F10158014151756039&show_text=true&width=500" width="500" height="703" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

However, if I change the height inside the iframe tag to something smaller than 703, say set it to 300. The page inside the content isn't scrollable, even I changed the `scrolling` to `yes`

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbrendan.domotor%2Fposts%2F10158014151756039&show_text=true&width=500" width="500" height="300" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="yes" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Check the Facebook page source, the `overflow` is set to `hidden` for the plugin class.
[image]

If I unset the `overflow`, the page can be scroll. But since it's an iframe embed, what can I do to unset the css in the child page which is hosted inside iframe? Thanks!

Comment: _“what can I do to unset the css in the child page which is hosted inside iframe?”_ - pretty much _nothing_, of course.

Comment: But perhaps leaving the iframe at its original given height, and sticking it into a container div with limited height and overflow:auto works for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpermalink.php%3Fstory_fbid%3D4730365237017608%26id%3D820869811300523&show_text=true&width=500" width="500" height="667" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Answer (score -1):

```html
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/post.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fbrendan.domotor%2Fposts%2F10158014151756039&show_text=true&width=500" width="500" height="703" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" allow="autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; picture-in-picture; web-share"></iframe>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?